# Send to connection - Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services, central-administration

Senario:

we have a user requirement where users want to share files with third party using sharepoint. We have a extranet sp site set up. Users will be doing send to connections from internal SP site to extranet (Record centre) for file sharing purposes.

I have configured sent to connection using central administration on internal SP site.  Central Admin –> General Application Settings –> Configure send to connections and add a new connection.

Issue:

When i select a file for send to connection i get error message saying "Extranet site can not be found or accessed"/ "The Extranet site is not properly configured for this request"

another error recived in ULS logs
OfficialFile::SubmitFile: Encountered WebException when sending file Site A to SiteB /_vti_bin/OfficialFile.asmx:
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Event id: 7022

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nishtha,

Similar question answered on following:
[I am Facing problem with "Send to connection" in SharePoint Server 2010.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/7908ffcc-60ef-4fc0-afe2-aed343a1e135)

If the above doesn't works for you, then try this: 
[Defining a "Send To" between two sub-sites within a site collection](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/11904d01-5759-41af-80d5-a3a9234486b5)

I found the article written by Steven Andrews on NothingButSharePoint.com:
[SharePoint: Common problems when creating a new "Send To" location](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/SharePoint-Common-problems-when-creating-a-new-Send-To-location.aspx)

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have followed the steps as mentioned in the link you specified but no joy. I've checked ULS logs and i am getting "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized". Do you think i may have to pass the authentication details somewhere?

Comment: I have updated the answer, I hope the threads given will help you resolve your issue!

Comment: Thanks again. I have also seen below error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ValidateFormDigest(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ValidateFormDigest(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName)

Comment: Nishtha, that is weird..! don't know about this - sorry!

Comment: I have started using manage copies rather than send to connection since its working without any issues.

Comment: Okay, good to hear you got your results! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Add application pool account your internal SP site run from to the Web Service Submitters group of extranet (Record centre).